# Jquery : How do i add a delay after function

Tags: jquery, function, delay

I want to add a delay to 4 functions i have.

I tried to add delay like i did here, but that doesn't work.

```
$('.navList .li1').toggleClass('li1Active');
$('.navList .li2').delay(2000).toggleClass('li2Active');
$('.navList .li3').delay(2000).toggleClass('li3Active');
$('.navList .li4').delay(2000).toggleClass('li4Active');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call function like this and set interval

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.navList .li1').toggleClass('li1Active');
      //create function and call in  setTimeout
     function addActive() {     
      $('.navList .li2').toggleClass('li2Active');
      $('.navList .li3').toggleClass('li3Active');
      $('.navList .li4').toggleClass('li4Active');
     }

     // use setTimeout() to execute
     setTimeout(addActive, 2000);

    });
```

Comment: isn't there a way to just use delay() or something more simple?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");

for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    highlight(elem[i], i*2000);
}

function highlight(elem, timeout) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(elem).toggleClass("red");
  }, timeout)
}
```

Comment: Second parameter of `toggleClass` is state, you used jquery ui

Comment: @Mohammad Yes I forgot to mention the JQuery UI. Second parameter is duration.

Comment: @rutgervs Please be precise on your question. I guess, your requirement was not about delay actually. You wanted to highlight the list of elements one by one by a regular time interval.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a delay before doing something. So better way is to call a function and pass the selector and class to toggle there. Like this:

```
function addDelay(selector, toggleClass, delay) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(selector).toggleClass(toggleClass);
  }, delay);
}
```

Then call the function like so :

```
$('.navList .li1').toggleClass('li1Active');
addDelay('.navList .li2', 'li2Active', 2000);
addDelay('.navList .li3', 'li3Active', 2000);
addDelay('.navList .li4', 'li4Active', 2000);
```

Comment: Edited the original code, you can see the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mkrptl89/2fchser9/3/

Comment: If you want the delay of 2 seconds before each toggle class, you need to pass 2000, 4000 and 6000 as the delay value.  Like I have done here: http://jsfiddle.net/mkrptl89/2fchser9/4/. From the sample code you have posted, it seems like you want the toggleClass to be executed after 2000 on rest of the li elements.